# How to identify n-gram before tokenization in stanford core-nlp?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the core-nlp annotation pipeline with default settings all through from tokenizing until ner_tags. I did observe that the "tokenizer" module is identifying , say "Vice President" as two individual tokens {vice,President} resulting in ner_tags identification as {o,TITLE} instead of {Vice President} and  {TITLE}. How can I get the tokenizer to identify "Vice president" as one single token , that help Ner_Tags to identify titles appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

What properties are you using to get TITLE as an NER tag? This is not one of the standard tags, and if you're using the TokensRegexNER annotator (e.g., for  the `kbp` annotator) multi-word titles like 'vice president' should be picked up. It works on corenlp.run at least.

In general, it's not the tokenizer's job to collapse NER spans into a single mention. The tokenizer should separate 'vice' and 'president' into different tokens, both of which should be marked TITLE by an appropriate NER annotator. You may be interested in the `entitymention` annotator, which groups contiguous NER tags into NER mentions -- this would give you 'vice president' as a single mention, rather than two tokens both marked as TITLE. These mentions can be retrieved using the [mentions annotation](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/28eee7f1904b845dac8a71b84990457e5edecc27/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreAnnotations.java#L1103) on a sentence CoreMap, or using the [`List<String> mention(String nerTag)`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/f4d67ab8823097083787afa4779f0770d99bbb4c/src/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.java#L521) or [`List<String> mentions()`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/f4d67ab8823097083787afa4779f0770d99bbb4c/src/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Sentence.java#L552) functions in the [simple API](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html).